# Need Shiro C# client

Tags: c#, shiro

As per detailed architecture http://shiro.apache.org/architecture.html
Apache shiro support C# clients but I was not able to find a good documentation/example on how to create one. If you can are aware any documentation or ideas on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Shiro can *function* with C# clients, but it itself does not provide a C# library.

The architecture diagram in your link shows that any client technology can work with a Shiro-enabled server as long as the client can communicate with the server, sending a session ID or principals collection with each request to the server.

Apache Shiro does not (currently) provide libraries for any platform other than the JVM (which means that things like Groovy, JRuby, Scala, etc - and of course Java - can all use Shiro today).

(I am a Apache Shiro team member).

P.S. If anyone wants to provide a lightweight implementation of the Subject interface in C# that can communicate with a Shiro-enabled server, I'm personally definitely open to collaboration!  Please discuss on the Shiro dev list.

Comment: Thanks Les for taking time and explaining this really appreciate your commitment to shiro. Currently I am evaluating shiro security model but I have the challenge of interacting with legacy windows clients and was exploring my options. So looks like the currently the way to to do this is host shiro in some server and make C# web requests.